# Nine Obscure Fellows

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-crosswords, literature

The names of nine fellows are concealed in this peculiar verse.  Find the names and provide your exegesis.

An apple for Charlemagne,
one that takes great steps,
returning in *Skyrim* or *Oblivion*,
and flag unfurled.

Dave's mentor, venerable sage,
in high spirits!
That way the celebration.

Most of sweet lime drink coming to me;
go sell a pretzel??

---

This is my first puzzle here.  If you have any suggestions for improvement, please share!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prem has the solution:

> The "obscure fellows" are the nine members of the Fellowship of the Ring in JRR Tolkien's *Lord of the Rings*.

I think some of the explanations are not quite right, however. The lines of the riddle are cryptic clues.

An apple for Charlemagne,

> **PIPPIN**: double definition; one of several [types of apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippin_apple) and the [eldest son of Charlemagne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepin_the_Hunchback). ✻

one that takes great steps,

> **STRIDER**: simple definition. Strider is Aragorn's nickname, used on his first encounter with the Hobbits

returning in Skyrim or Oblivion,

> **BOROMIR**: hidden backwards in skyRIM OR OBlivion.

and flag unfurled.

> **GANDALF**: anagram ("unfurled") of AND FLAG.  ✻

Dave's mentor, venerable sage,

> **SAMWISE**: SAM (or Samuel, who is King David's mentor in the Old Testament) plus WISE (venerable sage). I didn't get the OT reference, so many thanks to dennisdeems for the explanation in the coments below. ✻

in high spirits!

> **MERRY**: simple definition. ✻

That way the celebration.

> **FRODO**: "To and FRO" is this way and that way and a DO is a party.  (✻)

Most of sweet lime drink coming to me;

> **GIMLI**: Most of [GIMLet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimlet_%28cocktail%29) (sweet lime drink) plus I (me). ✻

go sell a pretzel??

> **LEGOLAS**: Anagram ("pretzel") of GO SELL A.

The answers marked with ✻ have already been given by Prem, although not necessarily with the same or full explanation.

Comment: Well done!  The only clue you didn't explain completely was for Samwise: in the bible, Samuel is David's mentor.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't make the connection from Sam and Dave to Samuel and King David. (Sam and Dave are bad google terms. And the OT is admittedly not my forte.)

Comment: Nor mine; I think I got most of my biblical knowledge from singing in school choir. :)

Comment: Yaaaaaay a cryptic crossword convert! Welcome @dennisdeems :D

Answer (score 7):

Short answer :

> http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Fellowship_of_the_Ring
>  9 MEMBERS

Details :

> "AND FLAG" anagram for **GANDALF**
>  "HIGH SPIRITS" = **MERRY**
>  "APPLE" = **PIPPIN**
>  "great steps" = **Legolas**
>  "venerable sage" = **SamWise Gamgee**
>  "returning" because he was gone, err Aragone, err **Aragorn**
>  "sweet lime drink" is gimlet "cocktail made of gin or vodka and lime juice" so **Gimli**
>  "pretzel" + http://www.boromir.ro/en/shop/pretzels-8 = **Boromir**
>  "celebration" + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit_Day = **Frodo**

Comment: I agree with your overall answer, but I think you haven't got all the clues right. For example, the one "returning in Sky**rim or Ob**livion" is Boromir.

Comment: Wouldn't Great Steps be Aragorn (aka Strider) too?

Comment: Upvoted, but you missed some.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure about my logic, so I'll take a stab before getting in entirely to solve this...*

Is the first fellow

> [Charles Appleton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Appleton_(academic))
>  Charles is a fellow of England's Oxford University, which sort of connects with the title.

Comment: @dennisdeems: Could this be the right connect?